# Oracle decode logic implementation using Slick

Tags: oracle, scala, slick

I have following problem - there is sql with DECODE oracle function:

```
SELECT u.URLTYPE, u.URL
  FROM KAA.ENTITYURLS u
JOIN KAA.ENTITY e 
  ON decode(e.isurlconfigured, 0, e.urlparentcode, 1, e.CODE, 
    NULL)=u.ENTITYCODE
JOIN CASINO.Casinos c ON e.casinocode = c.code
             WHERE e.NAME = $entityName
             AND C.NAME = $casinoName
```

I'm trying to realize this sql in my slick code , like:

```
val queryUrlsEntityName = for {
 entityUrl <- entityUrls
 entity <- entities.filter(e => e.name.trim===entityName &&
      entityUrl.entityCode.asColumnOf[Option[Int]]==(e.isURLConfigured match 
         { 
           case Some(0) => e.urlParentCode
           case Some(1) => e.code.asColumnOf[Option[Int]]
           case _ => None
         }
           )
       )
       casino <- casinos.filter(_.name.trim===casinoName) if 
 entity.casinoCode==casino.code
      } yield (entityUrl)
```

But I don't understand how can I implement of matching of values in line

```
case Some(0) => e.urlParentCode
```

because I'm getting error

```
  constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
  [error]  found   : Some[A]
  [error]  required: slick.lifted.Rep[Option[Int]]
  [error]            case Some(0) => e.urlParentCode
```

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0):

You should rewrite your code in pattern-matching section so you could compare required `Rep[Option[Int]]` - to left type, in your case it's  `Option[Int]`, or transform `Rep[Option[Int]]` to `Option[Int]` type. `Rep` is only the replacement to the column datatype in slick. I would prefer the first variant - this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30144204/6860682) shows how to make the transformation from `Rep`, or you can use `map` directly:

```
map(u => (u.someField)).result.map(_.headOption.match { 
  case Some(0) => .....
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I've changed my code to:
`entityUrl.entityCode.asColumnOf[Option[Int]] == e.isURLConfigured.result.map(_ match {
          case Some(0) => e.urlParentCode
          case Some(1) => e.code.asColumnOf[Option[Int]]
          case _ => None
        }
        )`
Looks like it's working..

Comment: @Vladimir Lubenchenko if it was helpful, please approve my answer

Comment: Sorry, I've tried to approve your answer, but unsuccessfully. Error is "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score"